# NSFileManager - URLsForDirectory... or URLForDirectory

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

`-[NSFileManager URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:]` requires a single NSSearchPathDomainMask and returns a single URL. (The `...appropriateForURL:create:error:` part is a bit confusing in documentation.)

`-[NSFileManager URLsForDirectory:inDomains:]` allows you to create a bit-mask for the domains parameter and returns an array of URLs.

It seems to me there is overlap between these two methods. If my goal is to get the Documents, or Library, or etc directory from an iOS app's sandbox, when should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The standard way to get access to the Documents directory (or other similar directories) is code like the following:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = paths[0];
```

This is similar to doing:

```
NSArray *URLs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
NSURL *documentsURL = URLs[0];
```

The key difference is the first gives you the path as an `NSString` while the second gives you the path as an `NSURL`.

The other method can be used by doing:

```
NSURL *documentsURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
```

You can pass `NO` for the Documents directory because it always exists. You should pass `YES` for the application support directory since it doesn't exist by default. And ideally you should not pass in `nil` for the error so you can see what happened if the method call returns `nil`.

Any of these three approaches work. Use the 1st if you want the path as a string. Use the 3rd if you want it as a URL. Use the 2nd if you have the rare need to pass in more than one domain.

Comment: From Apple's Documentation: `You should consider using the NSFileManager methods URLsForDirectory:inDomains: and URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:. which return URLs, which are the preferred format.`

Comment: That's true if you want URLs. If you want the path as an NSString, then what I posted is fine.

Comment: note that the default NSFileManager fetched from [[NSFileManager defaultManager] isn't threadsafe.
Therefore use an instance of it, if you do read/write operations in multiple queues(threads). [[NSFileManager alloc] init]

Comment: @Hulvej From the docs for `NSFileManager`: `The methods of the shared NSFileManager object can be called from multiple threads safely.`. The recommendation is to create your own instance of `NSFileManager` if you need to work with `NSFileManagerDelegate` methods.